How to create hyperlinks in headers for unnumbered chapters?
I'm working on a LaTeX document where I want the headers of all pages in each chapter to contain hyperlinks to the corresponding chapter's first page. This works perfectly for numbered chapters, but I encounter issues with unnumbered chapters such as "Contents", "Summary", "Acronyms" and "Bibliography".
I believe the problem lies in how I'm establishing the link to the chapter:
\hyperlink{chapter.\thechapter}{\leftmark}
This command correctly links to numbered chapters (like "Introduction"), but for unnumbered chapters, the hyperlinks do not work as expected. Instead of linking to the appropriate section, they seem to refer back to the last numbered chapter (e.g., "Bibliography" refers to "Conclusion") or to the end of the document (e.g., "Summary" points to the last page).
I don't know how to correctly reference automatically generated chapters (like "Contents" or "Bibliography") and those created with \chapter*{}.
How can I modify my LaTeX code to ensure that hyperlinks in the headers correctly jump to the first page of the chapter they are in?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Here is a minimal working example with its bibliography file:
File: example.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace} % For setting line spacing
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfa,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % For hyperlinks
\usepackage{xpatch} % To be able to change the color of the header line
\usepackage[bf,rm,medium,compact]{titlesec} % Settings for titles
\usepackage[nottoc, notbib]{tocbibind}% Remove ToC and Bibliography from ToC
\usepackage{doi} % for doi
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext} % For dummy text
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[expansion=true,stretch=30,shrink=30]{microtype}

\doublespacing%
\hypersetup{linkcolor=violet,citecolor=violet,urlcolor=violet,filecolor=violet}

%%% STYLING OF HEADERS %%%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\textbf{\nouppercase{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\hyperlink{chapter.\thechapter}{\leftmark}\hypersetup{linkcolor=violet}}}} % Left header with hyperlink in black
\chead{}
\rhead{\textbf{\thepage}}
\xpretocmd\headrule{\color{violet}}{}{\PatchFailed}
%%% END OF STYLING OF HEADERS %%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}\centering{\vspace*{7cm}{\Huge\textbf{Title}}\\[1.5cm]{\Large Author}\\[1cm]{\large \today}}\end{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{fancy}

    \pdfbookmark[1]{Table of Contents}{toc}\tableofcontents

    \clearpage
    \phantomsection\chapter*{Summary}\markboth{Summary}{}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}\label{chap:summary}\lipsum[1-3]

    \clearpage
    \phantomsection\chapter*{Acronyms}\markboth{Acronyms}{}\label{chap:acronyms}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
    \blindlist{itemize}[17]

    \chapter{Introduction}\markboth{Introduction}{}\label{chap:intro}\section{Sect 1}\subsection{Sub 1}\lipsum[11]\subsection{Sub 2}According to Clark \cite{clark2019blockchain}, blockchain provides a decentralized and secure way to record transactions \citep[see][p.~345-356]{white2020datascience}, which has numerous applications beyond cryptocurrencies \citep{author2023article, garcia2022robotics}.\section{Sect 2}\subsection{Sub 1}\lipsum[12]\subsection{Sub 2}The concept of blockchain was introduced with Bitcoin \citep{martinez2019conference}. It has various uses \citep{smith2019book}.\section{Sect 3}\subsection{Sub 1}\lipsum[13]\subsection{Sub 2}One application of blockchain is chain management \citep{doe2022research, lee2021study}. Rodriguez \cite{rodriguez2020nlp} highlights several.\section{Sect 4}\lipsum[14]Blockchain technology has potential \citep{kim2020analysis, brown2018survey, williams2017bigdata}. Miller \cite{miller2018ai} discusses the benefits \citep[see][chap.~2]{johnson2021deep}.

    \chapter{Conclusion}\markboth{Conclusion}{}\label{chap:conclusion}\section{Sect 1}\lipsum[5]\section{Sect 2}\lipsum[6]\section{Sect 3}\lipsum[7]

    \clearpage
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}\bibliography{example}

\end{document}

File: example.bib
@article{author2023article,
    author = {John Author},
    title = {An Example Article},
    journal = {Journal of Examples},
    year = {2023},
    volume = {1},
    pages = {1--10},
    doi = {10.1234/je.2023.00101},
}

@book{smith2019book,
    author = {Jane Smith},
    title = {A Comprehensive Guide},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    year = {2019},
}

@article{doe2022research,
    author = {Alice Doe},
    title = {Innovative Research in AI},
    journal = {AI Journal},
    year = {2022},
    volume = {15},
    pages = {101--120},
    doi = {10.1234/aij.2022.01501},
}

@article{lee2021study,
    author = {Bob Lee},
    title = {A Study on Machine Learning},
    journal = {Machine Learning Today},
    year = {2021},
    volume = {8},
    pages = {45--60},
    doi = {10.5678/mlt.2021.08045},
}

@article{kim2020analysis,
    author = {Carol Kim},
    title = {Analysis of Data Structures},
    journal = {Data Science Journal},
    year = {2020},
    volume = {12},
    pages = {200--215},
    doi = {10.9101/dsj.2020.12200},
}

@article{brown2018survey,
    author = {David Brown},
    title = {Survey on Neural Networks},
    journal = {Neural Network Review},
    year = {2018},
    volume = {5},
    pages = {75--90},
    doi = {10.2345/nnr.2018.05075},
}

@book{johnson2021deep,
    author = {Emily Johnson},
    title = {Deep Learning Fundamentals},
    publisher = {Tech Press},
    year = {2021},
}

@article{williams2017bigdata,
    author = {Frank Williams},
    title = {Big Data Analytics},
    journal = {Data Insights},
    year = {2017},
    volume = {3},
    pages = {30--50},
    doi = {10.6789/di.2017.03030},
}

@inproceedings{martinez2019conference,
    author = {George Martinez},
    title = {Advances in Quantum Computing},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the Quantum Computing Conference},
    year = {2019},
    pages = {100--110},
}

@article{rodriguez2020nlp,
    author = {Hannah Rodriguez},
    title = {Natural Language Processing Techniques},
    journal = {Journal of Computational Linguistics},
    year = {2020},
    volume = {10},
    pages = {150--170},
    doi = {10.3456/jcl.2020.10150},
}

@book{miller2018ai,
    author = {Ian Miller},
    title = {Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach},
    publisher = {AI Books},
    year = {2018},
}

@article{garcia2022robotics,
    author = {Jessica Garcia},
    title = {Robotics and Automation},
    journal = {Robotics Journal},
    year = {2022},
    volume = {7},
    pages = {80--95},
    doi = {10.4567/rj.2022.07080},
}

@inproceedings{thompson2021cybersecurity,
    author = {Kevin Thompson},
    title = {Cybersecurity Challenges},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the International Cybersecurity Symposium},
    year = {2021},
    pages = {200--210},
}

@article{martin2016iot,
    author = {Laura Martin},
    title = {Internet of Things: Trends and Future},
    journal = {IoT Journal},
    year = {2016},
    volume = {2},
    pages = {10--25},
    doi = {10.7890/iotj.2016.02010},
}

@book{white2020datascience,
    author = {Michael White},
    title = {Data Science for Beginners},
    publisher = {Data Press},
    year = {2020},
}

@article{clark2019blockchain,
    author = {Nancy Clark},
    title = {Blockchain Technology},
    journal = {Journal of Blockchain Research},
    year = {2019},
    volume = {4},
    pages = {60--75},
    doi = {10.8901/jbr.2019.04060},
}

@article{adams2023cyber,
    author = {Olivia Adams},
    title = {Cybersecurity in the Modern World},
    journal = {Cybersecurity Journal},
    year = {2023},
    volume = {9},
    pages = {25--40},
    doi = {10.1111/cj.2023.09025},
}

@article{baker2022cloud,
    author = {Paul Baker},
    title = {Cloud Computing Advances},
    journal = {Cloud Tech Journal},
    year = {2022},
    volume = {11},
    pages = {55--70},
    doi = {10.2222/ctj.2022.11055},
}

@article{evans2021iotsecurity,
    author = {Quinn Evans},
    title = {IoT Security Measures},
    journal = {IoT Security Journal},
    year = {2021},
    volume = {6},
    pages = {100--115},
    doi = {10.3333/iotsj.2021.06100},
}


Can you amend your MWE to add the documentclass. Also try to add \frontmatter \mainmatter and backmatter and see if your *chapters  are linking properly in the ToC first. You might be able you achieve what you need with MakeLinkTarget documentation is in the latest versions of hyperref. It is also in source2e, but has no documentation there.

@yannisl I don't understand what you mean with "add the documentclass". The first line is \documentclass[12pt]{report}, should I add something else?
As my document class is report, I believe that \frontmatter, etc are not available. I will see if changing it to book doesn't break my whole document. But thank you for your suggestion, if it works, it might just solve it easily!

Oops I did not notice you had it.

I did the change of document class to book and added the \frontmatter, etc, and it all worked well, but it didn't fix the problem. I am now trying Ulrike's method.

Ulrike is the hyperref expert and her method works well.

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[pdfa,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % For hyperlinks
\usepackage[bf,rm,medium,compact]{titlesec} % Settings for titles
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=violet,citecolor=violet,urlcolor=violet,filecolor=violet}

%%% STYLING OF HEADERS %%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight=15pt
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\bfseries \leftmark} % Left header with hyperlink in black
\chead{}
\rhead{\textbf{\thepage}}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\markbothwithlink{m}{%
 \markboth{\protect\hyperlink{\@currentHref}{#1}}{}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]
 {\markbothwithlink{\thechapter~#1}} 
\renewcommand\bibsection{\chapter*{\bibname}\markbothwithlink{\bibname}}

\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/before}
{\NextLinkTarget{toc}
 \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{toc}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\markbothwithlink{\contentsname}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\chapter*{Summary}\label{chap:summary}
\markbothwithlink{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\lipsum

%to test second toc page:
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage} 

\chapter*{Acronyms}\label{chap:acronyms}
\markbothwithlink{Acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}

\lipsum

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\chapter{Conclusion}

\lipsum

%manual bibliography to test second page
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Jones(2021)]{test1} some bib

%to test second bib page
\newpage 
\bibitem[Doody(2024)]{test2} some bib

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}


Very good solution ++. If one wants to automate this by redefining the \makeschapterhead Is there a way to automate the generation of the label? I know the OP did not ask for it. Is this where MakeLinkTarget can be used?

Thank you for your response! Could you please explain the "\makeatletter...", "\renewcommand...", and "\AddToHook..." sections?
I have been able to modify all the "\chapter*{}" sections now, but I am still unsure of how to do it for the table of contents, bibliography, and other sections that I have, such as List of Figures and List of Tables.

@yannisl well actually one doesn't need a label. Unnumbered chapters set @currentHref too, I edited the answer.

@Zaida the code already handles the bibliography and the table of contents, for the list of figures copy the hook code and replace tableofcontents by listoffigures and toc by lof.

I have integrated it now and I think I understand what is happening in each command, so thank you very much again!
